# How to solve these type : If $a + b + c + d = 63$ then find the Maximum of $(a b+ b c+ c d)$

Tags: algebra

If `a + b + c + d == 63` then find the Maximum of `a b + b c + c d`.
I tried using `If`, `With`
but unable to get the solution/answer. Any help is appreciated.
The answer is 991.

Comment: `{a,b,c,d}>=0`?

Comment: `Maximize[{a b + b c + c d, a + b + c + d == 63}, {a, b, c, d}]` should work but does not, for some reason.

Comment: Aside from the problem being unbounded as @cvgmt pointed out, one can see from the Hessian that any critical point is a saddle point: `D[z /. First@ Solve[{z == a b + b c + c d, a + b + c + d == 63}, {z, d}], {{a, b, c}, 2}] // Eigenvalues // N`. On a bounded domain, the extrema will be on the boundary.

Comment: Need to add  a condition `{a, b, c, d} ∈ PositiveIntegers` or `{a, b, c, d} ∈ Integers,{a,b,c,d}>0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

```
Maximize[{a*b + b*c + c*d, 
  a + b + c + d == 63, {a, b, c, d} ∈ PositiveIntegers}, {a, 
  b, c, d}]
```

> `{991, {a -> 1, b -> 30, c -> 31, d -> 1}}`

**Original**

We must add some conditions since without it the question is unbounded.
See the example as below.

```
a b + b c + c d /. 
  FindInstance[{a + b + c + d == 63}, {a, b, c, d}, Reals, 20] // N
```

> `{5502.96, 6579.89, -10891.8, 2442.18, -6627.59, -7054.56, 2829.6, 415.69, 305.09, 918.08, 410.02, -6148.25, -6412.11, -10460.1, 1677.84, -4958.71, 1965.59, -2993.25, 315.68, -1949.59}`

```
Maximize[{a b + b c + c d, 
  a + b + c + d == 63, {a, b, c, d} >= 0}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> `{3969/4, {a -> 0, b -> 16, c -> 63/2, d -> 31/2}}`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

`QuadraticOptimization` can optimize quadratic functions with linear constraints:

```
QuadraticOptimization[-(a b + b c + c d), a + b + c + d == 63, {a, b, c, d}]
(* {a -> 0., b -> 31.5, c -> 31.5, d -> 0.} *)
```

Alternatively use `Solve` on the [KKT-conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions):

```
{D[a b + b c + c d + μ (a + b + c + d - 63), {{a, b, c, d}, 1}],
   a + b + c + d - 63} == 0 // Solve
(* {{a -> 0, b -> 63/2, c -> 63/2, d -> 0, μ -> -(63/2)}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it using the Lagrange multipliers technique as follows:

```
obj = a b + b c + c d;
L = obj + lambda (a + b + c + d - 63)
vars = Variables[L]
grad = Grad[L, vars]
sols = Solve[grad == 0, vars]
results = {obj, vars} /. sols[[1]]

(*{3969/4, {0, 63/2, 63/2, 0, -(63/2)}}*)
```